# How to make DataGridCell have the same border as its first son

Tags: wpf

I've been wondering why there is a small offset between the `DataGridCell` row and its content. Something like this, where the data grid cell has a white region around the green region:

[image: Example]

I've been struggling to remove that white region, i would like that the entire cell content becomes green.

Here is the code I've used so far:

```
<Style TargetType='DataGridCell'>
   <Setter Property='Padding'
           Value='0,0,0,0' />
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property='IsSelected'
               Value='True'>
         <Setter Property='TextElement.FontStyle'
                 Value='Italic' />
         <Setter Property='Foreground'
                 Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Foreground}" />
         <Setter Property='BorderBrush'
                 Value='DarkGray' />
         <Setter Property='BorderThickness'
                 Value='0,1' />
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `DataGridCell` has a control template with a `Border` that is shown when the cell is focused. Its `BorderThickness` is bound with a template binding, so you can just get rid of it by creating and applying a cell style that sets the `BorderThickness` to zero. However, you lose the visual feedback for keyboard and mouse focus as a result.

```
<DataGrid>
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Another option is to edit the control template of `DataGridCell` to remove the border altogether or change the color of the border and the background selectively, so that it is not visible in each state.